# How can I count the item of property as an array inside a class?

Tags: arrays, swift, class

How can I count the teamMember in team A?

```swift
class BasketBallTeam {
    var teamName: String
    var teamMember: [String]

    init(teamName: String, teamMember: [String]) {
        self.teamName = teamName
        self.teamMember = teamMember
    }
}

let highSchoolTeam: [BasketBallTeam] = [
    BasketBallTeam(teamName: "A", teamMember: [
        "John", "Sam", "Tom", "Ricky", "George"
    ]),
    BasketBallTeam(teamName: "B", teamMember: [
        "Jason", "Michael", "Daniel", "Henry", "David", "Luke"
    ]),
]
```

Comment: the `team` prefix in `teamName` and `teamMember` are redundant. Just name them `name` and `members`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this a lot, it would be best to create a dictionary that lets you easily access teams by their names:

```
struct BasketBallTeam {
    var name: String
    var members: [String]

    init(name: String, members: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.members = members
    }
}

let highSchoolTeams: [BasketBallTeam] = [
    BasketBallTeam(name: "A", members: [
        "John", "Sam", "Tom", "Ricky", "George"
    ]),
    BasketBallTeam(name: "B", members: [
        "Jason", "Michael", "Daniel", "Henry", "David", "Luke"
    ]),
]

let teamsByName = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    highSchoolTeams.lazy.map { team in (key: team.name, value: team) })
```

Which makes looking up any team by name fast and easy:

```
let teamA = teamsByName["A"]
let teamASize = teamA?.members.count
print(teamASize as Any)
```

If you only need to do this once, you can use `first(where:)`:

```
let teamA = highSchoolTeams.first(where: { $0.name == "A"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `count` it.

As `highSchoolTeam` is an array you have to get the `first` item

```
let numberOfMembers = highSchoolTeam.first?.teamMember.count
```

Please name `teamMember` in plural form `teamMembers` (or even `members`) to indicate the array

Comment: This won't work if `teamA` is added at an `index` other than the `first` one in `highSchoolTeam array`.

Comment: @PGDev In the original version of the question there was only one team. Someone (not the OP) added a second team.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count for each team as follows:

```
for team in highSchoolTeam {
    print(team.teamMember.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use,

1. `first(_:)` on `highSchoolTeam` to get the `team` where `teamName == "A"`.
2. `count` on `teamMember` to get the total `count` of `teamMembers` from the `BasketBallTeam object` obtained in step-1.

It goes like,

```
let teamAMemberCount = highSchoolTeam.first{ $0.teamName == "A" }?.teamMember.count

print(teamAMemberCount) //Output: 5
```